# Error on Enable-Migrations

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new with EF and I have an error when I try to run Enable-Migrations in PMC console :
Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s):

```
 "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///...\pa
ckages\EntityFramework.6.0.1\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)"
At ...\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.1\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:780 char:62
+     $utilityAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom <<<< ((Join-Path $ToolsPath EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll))
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException



You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At ...\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.1\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:781 char:50
+     $dispatcher = $utilityAssembly.CreateInstance <<<< (
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (CreateInstance:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Exception calling "CreateInstanceFrom" with "8" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///...\packages\EntityFramework.6.0.1\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is no t supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)"
At ...\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.1\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:809 char:31
+     $domain.CreateInstanceFrom <<<< (
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Answer (score 9):

I just ran into this on one of my co-worker's machine.  The solution was:

1. Uninstall EF NuGet package
2. Manually remove Entity Framework sections from the Web.Config/App.Config files
3. Close Visual Studio
4. Re-open the solution in Visual Studio
5. Reinstall the EF NuGet Package

Answer (score 3):

So openn the solution folder in file explorer, can you find the .dlls they are looking for in "Packages" folder then EntityFramework 6.0.1 folder? If not, there are two options:

1. Check your source control server, there is a possibility it was not downloaded to local workspace. if so, just get them manually from source control explorer if you are using TFS.
2. If the files were not on source control server either, I would recommend to uninstall EF 6.0.1 nuget, then manual delete the whole folder about ef in the Package folder above, and then reinstall it.

Comment: EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll was not in the packages folder. This fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. My project was stored in a network drive. There are many security policies applied to my PC. I moved my project to the local hard drive, and the problem was solved.

It seems like "EntityFramework.Powershell.utility.dll" is tring to use some powershell functionality, and the system is preventing to execute such calls, maybe because the dll that is calling powershell is not a local file.

In your case, make sure that you do not have any security policy or system configuration that would prevent your system execute the problematical extension from a non local drive (EntityFramework.Powershell.utility.dll)

Answer (score 1):

Faced similar problem. Reason of the problem was shifting of my code from one machine to another...Removing and then reinstalling entity framework solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Update the Entity Package from Package Manager Console or browser.