# error when using enable-migrations with entity framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework-6

I receive following error when using enable-migrations with the entity framework:

```
Exception lors de l'appel de «LoadFrom» avec «1» argument(s): «Impossible de charger le fichier ou  l'assembly 'file:///C:\Users\hassine\Desktop\NetExamRev\ExamenDotNet\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\too ls\EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll' ou une de ses dépendances. L'opération n'est pas prise en  charge. (Exception de HRESULT : 0x80131515)» Au caractère C:\Users\hassine\Desktop\NetExamRev\ExamenDotNet\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\Enti tyFramework.psm1:780 : 5
+     $utilityAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Join-P ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileLoadException   Impossible d’appeler une méthode dans une expression Null. Au caractère C:\Users\hassine\Desktop\NetExamRev\ExamenDotNet\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\Enti tyFramework.psm1:781 : 5
+     $dispatcher = $utilityAssembly.CreateInstance(
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation : (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull   Exception lors de l'appel de «CreateInstanceFrom» avec «8» argument(s): «Impossible de charger le  fichier ou l'assembly 'file:///C:\Users\hassine\Desktop\NetExamRev\ExamenDotNet\packages\EntityFramewor k.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.dll' ou une de ses dépendances. L'opération n'est pas prise  en charge. (Exception de HRESULT : 0x80131515)» Au caractère C:\Users\hassine\Desktop\NetExamRev\ExamenDotNet\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\Enti tyFramework.psm1:809 : 5
+     $domain.CreateInstanceFrom(
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileLoadException
```

Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide some code and if possible provide an error message which is actually English and not French :)

Comment: That looks like a package problem. Best solution might be removing EF from NUGET and re-adding it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25265015/error-on-enable-migrations